# How come toString() is a method that doesn't need an object?

Tags: javascript, string, object

The deeper I get into programming, the more old concepts I thought I knew confuse me. For example, the toString() method. How come I can apply this method to a variable thats not an object? Is it because toString() is a built in javascript method that can apply to all data types?

Comment: Which `toString` method? Do you mean `Object.prototype.toString`?

Comment: Liek the example below:
var message = "Hello world!";
var x = message.toUpperCase();
@CertainPerformance

Comment: So you're really asking about `String.prototype.toString`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I guess so, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly everything is an object in JavaScript. What you would call primitives (strings, numbers, etc.) all have methods:

```js
console.log("Message".toUpperCase());
console.log(123.toString());
```

So the reason you can apply `toString` to anything - even if it doesn't seem like an object - is because everything is really a kind of object, which means it can have methods. Here's some examples of `toString` on different things:

```js
console.log(123..toString());
console.log(["A", "B", "C"].toString());
console.log(typeof true.toString());
```

Comment: When you call `toString` on a primitive, usually you're just invoking the primitive-specific `toString `method. If you had actually been invoking `Object.prototype.toString`, you would have seen `[object String]`.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple different kinds of `toString` methods. There is `Object.prototype.toString`, which any object will inherit. There is also `Number.prototype.toString`, `Boolean.prototype.toString`, and `String.prototype.toString`.

When you do

```
'foo'.toString()
```

you're actually invoking `String.prototype.toString` - you're not invoking `Object.prototype.toString`.

```js
Object.prototype.toString = () => 'changed';
console.log('foo'.toString());
```

Although strings and other things *can* be interpreted as objects, and have `Object.prototype.toString` called on them, often you're just calling the *primitive-specific* method, like `Boolean.prototype.toString` or `String.prototype.toString`. (These prototypes *do* happen to inherit from `Object.prototype`, but the `Object.prototype.toString` method is shadowed over by the closer prototype method, and may well not even be considered)

Why do these methods exist for those primitives? Probably for the sake of consistency. If you have something that's not `undefined` or `null`, you'll know that you'll be able to call `toString` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about "prototypal inheritance". It is one of the most critical concepts of the javascript language to understand in my opinion.

The above answers are correct, but you aren't going to understand what they mean until you take some time to study this subject.

Hope that gives you some guidance!